# Хостинг Gandi — как объединить www.site.ru и site.ru?

Tags: хостинг

У клиента домен и хостинг на `Gandi.net` Пытаюсь разобраться, как сделать, чтобы один и тот же сайт работал и на голом домене, и на `www`.

Сначала создал сайт под `www.site.ru`. Под просто `site.ru` у них можно создать отдельный `VHost`, с отдельным контентом — не то, что нужно. Доступ - только `SFTP`, шелла нет, а через `SFTP` вроде бы нельзя создавать софтлинки.

**Upd.** не нашлось иного решения, кроме редиректа ( www-forwarding в терминах Ганди).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Их техподдержка посоветовала сделать через CNAME:

> If you want both URLs to point to the same folder, delete one of the
> virtual hosts (for example [www.site.com](http://www.site.com)).
> Then, go to the zone file editor, and replace the entry :
>
> www     CNAME   [gpaasXX.dc0.gandi.net](http://gpaasXX.dc0.gandi.net).
>
> with:
>
> www     CNAME   [site.com](http://site.com).

Answer (score 3):

А создание редиректа в htaccess не подойдет?

Comment: Вы с этим хостингом имели дело? Там всё не так тривиально.